# Generate pom.xml file (with dependency) for all the jars name/version I have in my text file

Tags: java, maven, github, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I have huge number of jars listed in text file along with its versions.
For ex:

- spring-jdbc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
- commons-codec.jar
- commons-fileupload.jar

.
.
.
.

This list goes on for 500+ jars.

**Problem: I need a pom.xml that comprises all these jars as dependency.
I need this for GHAS scanning in github to determine the EOL's**

Comment: Why do you have them in a text file? Furthermore spring jdbc in that version 4.3.6 is already ancient old.. (https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/versions) What about writing some Java code to generate that pom ?

Comment: These are the dependencies that are used by one of our application. I have just extracted the list of jars to a text file. The final output is, I would need all these jars listed as dependencies in a pom file.

Comment: Given you may not be able to assume all dependencies are built by maven, a quick-and-dirty approach would be to simply [add the jarfile as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project). Alternatively, you could `mvn install` the jarfiles with generated pom files per jar, allowing you to then keep the dependencies in one place across multiple projects. These are both stopgaps compared to actually going through and getting thr proper versions and maven strings per jar. For ones built with maven, the answer below will save time.

Comment: `These are the dependencies that are used by one of our application. `  and how does the app get those jars? How to build your project?

Answer (score 1):

Any jar file that is built by maven should have `pom.properties` file under `META-INF\maven\${groupId}\${artifactId}`. This `pom.properties` file should contain the `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` of the jar

Personally I'd write a gradle/groovy script to iterate the list of jar files, extract the `pom.properties` file and write a `pom.xml` snippet (since gradle has really nice api's for iterating files and extracting from zipfiles etc).

This could also be done in java although it would be more verbose (using `ZipInputStream`)

Here's what a gradle script might look like to achieve this

```
tasks.register('xmlDependencies') {
   doLast {
      def textFile = file('c:/path/to/textfile.txt')
      def deps = []
      for (String line : textFile.readLines()) {
         File jar = file(line)
         Set<File> propFiles = zipTree(jar).matching { include 'META-INF/maven/**/pom.properties' }.files
         if (propFiles.size() != 1) {
            logger.lifecycle "Found ${propFiles.size()} pom.properties in ${jar}"
         } else {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(propFiles[0])

            deps << """|<dependency>
                       |   <groupId>${props.groupId}</groupId>            
                       |   <artifactId>${props.artifactId}</artifactId>            
                       |   <version>${props.version}</version>            
                       |</dependency>""".stripMargin()
         }
      }
      File pomFile = file("$buildDir/pom.xml")
      pomFile.text = deps.join('\r\n')
      logger.lifecycle "Wrote to $pomFile" 
   }
}
```